# Best pythonic way to insert quotes into a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm dealing with [this python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue3073) while writing my own reverse proxy. The server is sending my proxy this `Set-Cookie` response header:

```
workgroup_session_id=ilDJtR0rE1AG28C9ZxKLHj8TBtcT89sw; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 02-Dec-2012 5:57:25 GMT; HttpOnly
```

I am loading this string into a `SimpleCookie` instance from the `Cookie` module. Unfortunately, because of the bug that I referenced above, when I later pull `expires` out of the morsel dictionary it returns `Sun,`. I have found that I can overcome this bug by adding quotes around the `Expires` component of the `Set-Cookie` header (or adding quotes around any key / value pair that contains spaces in the value).

So this:

```
workgroup_session_id=ilDJtR0rE1AG28C9ZxKLHj8TBtcT89sw; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 02-Dec-2012 5:57:25 GMT; HttpOnly
```

Would become:

```
workgroup_session_id=ilDJtR0rE1AG28C9ZxKLHj8TBtcT89sw; Path=/; Expires="Sun, 02-Dec-2012 5:57:25 GMT"; HttpOnly
```

And this:

```
test=a b c; Path=/; Expires=a b c; HttpOnly
```

Would become:

```
test="a b c"; Path=/; Expires="a b c"; HttpOnly
```

I know that I could break the string into tokens and loop through them looking for spaces, then reconstruct the string, but I am curious what the best **performing** solution would be. As I mentioned, this is a reverse proxy that could potentially handle a few hundred requests a second, so I'd like this substitution to be as fast as possible.

Would a regular expression substitution (pre-compiled of course) be efficient? I've heard that regular expressions are pretty heavy....

Comment: Sorry, but I **have** to ask - why are you writing your own?

Comment: It's a fair question... Unique django project that I want serving visualization generated on a Windows PC. Believe it or not, it really works great. Well, besides this little bug (which only affects IE).

Comment: thanks - didn't assume you were doing it for fun - but, I'm struggling to see the reason that you just can't use an existing proxy - the idea of a proxy being that all of this **doesn't** have to be **handled** in anyway - just get/sent about... (sorry - maybe I just don't fully get the question...)

Comment: I guess I spun my own because I want absolute control of the response / request headers (on both sides of the proxy) within django.

Comment: It's not a product that is designed to work in the way I'm using it, so I have to wrap my own django-auth into the requests that go through the reverse proxy to the visualization server.

Comment: Okay - it's late here, but I'd probably have a look at middleware... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs

Comment: I'm very familiar with writing django middleware- my reverse proxy has a middleware component. I'm really just looking for an answer to the string substitution issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this regex:

```
import re
header = re.sub("(?<==)[^;]* [^;]*", r'"\g<0>"', header)
```

This inserts quotes around whatever follows after a `=` until the next `;` (or end of string), but only if there is at least one space in-between.

```
>>> header = 'test=a b c; Path=/; Expires=a b c; HttpOnly'
>>> re.sub("(?<==)[^;]* [^;]*", r'"\g<0>"', header)
'test="a b c"; Path=/; Expires="a b c"; HttpOnly'
>>> header = "workgroup_session_id=ilDJtR0rE1AG28C9ZxKLHj8TBtcT89sw; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 02-Dec-2012 5:57:25 GMT; HttpOnly"
>>> re.sub("(?<==)[^;]* [^;]*", r'"\g<0>"', header)
'workgroup_session_id=ilDJtR0rE1AG28C9ZxKLHj8TBtcT89sw; Path=/; Expires="Sun, 02-Dec-2012 5:57:25 GMT"; HttpOnly'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to put quotes just around the date following Expires, or any arbitrary date that appears anywhere in the header? If it's the former, try this:

```
header = "workgroup_session_id=ilDJtR0rE1AG28C9ZxKLHj8TBtcT89sw; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 02-Dec-2012 5:57:25 GMT; HttpOnly"
print(header.replace('Expires=', 'Expires="').replace('GMT', 'GMT"'))
```

Comment: Hadn't though of that approach... Very creative hack. I like it. Not pretty, but quick and dirty.